# Kubernetes web filtering solution

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, geolocation, google-kubernetes-engine, webfiltering

I'm using GKE and want to restrict my external load balancers from unwanted traffic. I found two options that problematic for me:

1. Nginx plus + maxmind solution for geo filtering - I'm looking for an open source solution (and the maxmind lite is not available anymore).
2. GKE Ingress + Cloud armor, but I'm using nginx and other load balancers and not the GKE Ingress.

I'm looking for a better solution, maybe in a global kubernetes level implemented as a daemonset or a regular deployment proxy.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest checking out : https://lab.wallarm.com/how-to-protect-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-wallarm-configuration-and-finetuning-part-2-of-3/

And nice **Wallarm WAF ingress controller** : https://github.com/wallarm/ingress

With `Nginx ingress`, there are options to increase to security

**[ModSecurity](https://cloudzone.io/implementing-waf-and-mutual-tls-on-kubernetes-with-nginx-modsecurity/)** at application level metadata and proxy payload size management.

For DDoS protection, you can use the [rate-limiting](https://medium.com/@chadsaun/mitigating-a-ddos-attack-with-ingress-nginx-and-kubernetes-12f309072367) and connection handling option

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: '2'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: '60'
```

you can whitelist the List of IPs also.

Comment: this can be helpful, but what about filtering in a country level? If my application runs on US I would like only IPs from US could access it, which is the solution of maxmind. Do you familiar with a free alternative for countries IP ranges databases?